# How can JSONObject.toString(int) throw JSONException?

Tags: java, json, jsonexception

I noticed this in the [JSONObject.toString(int)](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#toString(int)) documentation

> Throws: JSONException - If the object contains an invalid number.

How could the object contain an invalid number if the NaN/Infinity check is done beforehand (either at parsing and in statements like `.put("blah", Double.NAN)` ?
Which statements would throw that exception?

I also read in the docs that [.toString()](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#toString()) without args doesn't throw anything, so I thought that the exception could be related to the integer passed as parameter; but even with zero, negative or Integer.MAX/MIN_VALUE it still works.

So when one should expect .toString(int) to throw an exception and how should one handle that?

Comment: i am not sure, but i would expect an exception to be thrown if `indentFactor <= 0`

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the `parameter` but has to do with the `object` you are calling `toString()` on. If that `JSONObject` has an invalid number in it then it would throw an exception...

Comment: in previous versions of JSONObject probably it was possible to create an invalid structure and get an error only when printing it out. After adding validation while creating this structure in newer versions, they either forgot to remove this @throws from `toString(int)` or forgot to add to the `toString()` from the very beginning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method not throws an exception because it has to override a signature of `public void toString()` method of `java.lang.Object`. In `org.json.JSONObject` generic `toString()` method actually fails silently since the source code is:

```
/**
 * Make a JSON text of this JSONObject. For compactness, no whitespace is
 * added. If this would not result in a syntactically correct JSON text,
 * then null will be returned instead.
 * <p>
 * Warning: This method assumes that the data structure is acyclical.
 *
 * @return a printable, displayable, portable, transmittable representation
 *         of the object, beginning with <code>{</code>&nbsp;<small>(left
 *         brace)</small> and ending with <code>}</code>&nbsp;<small>(right
 *         brace)</small>.
 */
public String toString() {
    try {
        return this.toString(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This method relies on `toString(int)` method, and in case that it throws the exception, it catch it and returns null.

According to the `toString(int)` description, the exception is thrown when `org.json.JSONObject` has an invalid number inside one of its elements; but looking at code could be possible that this exception is thrown for other reasons.

When you use `toString(int)` the stack trace finally calls `write()`  method to parse the object itself, the exception could be thrown for some of transformations from json objects to string:

```
static final Writer writeValue(Writer writer, Object value,
            int indentFactor, int indent) throws JSONException, IOException {
        if (value == null || value.equals(null)) {
            writer.write("null");
        } else if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
            ((JSONObject) value).write(writer, indentFactor, indent);
        } else if (value instanceof JSONArray) {
            ((JSONArray) value).write(writer, indentFactor, indent);
        } else if (value instanceof Map) {
            new JSONObject((Map<String, Object>) value).write(writer, indentFactor, indent);
        } else if (value instanceof Collection) {
            new JSONArray((Collection<Object>) value).write(writer, indentFactor,
                    indent);
        } else if (value.getClass().isArray()) {
            new JSONArray(value).write(writer, indentFactor, indent);
        } else if (value instanceof Number) {
            writer.write(numberToString((Number) value));
        } else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
            writer.write(value.toString());
        } else if (value instanceof JSONString) {
            Object o;
            try {
                o = ((JSONString) value).toJSONString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new JSONException(e);
            }
            writer.write(o != null ? o.toString() : quote(value.toString()));
        } else {
            quote(value.toString(), writer);
        }
        return writer;
    }
```

However if as you said in your question (and @Carlos Rodriguez comments) all the checks are performed when the object is created, probably `toString(int)` method never thrown an exception.

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 1):

It helps to look at the implementation of `JSONObject.toString(int)` and `JSONObject.toString()`:

```
public String toString(int indentFactor) throws JSONException {
    StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
    synchronized (w.getBuffer()) {
        return this.write(w, indentFactor, 0).toString();
    }
}
```

The `write` method writes to a `Writer` and rethrows any IOException as JSONException. If your analysis is right, then such an IOException would never occur, since StringWriters also don't throw IOExceptions. So it seems merely an implementation decision to let this method throw an JSONException and the documentation is misleading.

```
public String toString() {
    try {
        return this.toString(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The `toString()` implementation confirms this analysis: Here the API designers decided to catch any Exception which would only make sense if an Exception is *never* thrown.

It would have probably been better to move the `try-catch` into the `toString(int)` to free both method from the throw clause in their signatures.

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into this problem.

Here is an example that will cause the `JSONObject.toString(int)` method to throw a `JSONException`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("num", Double.NaN);
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("map", map);
    obj.toString(0);
}
```

In my opinion the exception should be thrown by the `JSONObject.put()` method, but apparently no check is done here...